# Kyle Simpson asyncify function from You Don't Know JS: Async & Performance

Tags: javascript

If someone can explain in detail what this function does?
What is this part doing:  fn = orig_fn.bind.apply(orig_fn,

Thanks.

```
function asyncify(fn) {
        var orig_fn = fn,
            intv = setTimeout( function(){
                intv = null;
                if (fn) fn();
            }, 0 )
        ;

        fn = null;

        return function() {
            // firing too quickly, before `intv` timer has fired to
            // indicate async turn has passed?
            if (intv) {
                fn = orig_fn.bind.apply(
                    orig_fn,
                    // add the wrapper's `this` to the `bind(..)`
                    // call parameters, as well as currying any
                    // passed in parameters
                    [this].concat( [].slice.call( arguments ) )
                );
            }
            // already async
            else {
                // invoke original function
                orig_fn.apply( this, arguments );
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: The check for intv is because if the resulting next-tick'd function was called in the same tick that asyncify() was called, intv would still be defined. But I can't say what the point of orig_fn vs fn is. when fn is bound to orig_fn, fn is never used again except in that assignment -- in other words the assignment is pointless (unless I'm just missing something...)

Comment: @Semicolon: `fn` is called in the `setTimeout` callback, which may or many not happen after the function it returns that sets `fn` is called.

Comment: Yup, I just saw it after I typed that and was about to comment-edit :)

Comment: (That said, I am finding the *point* of parts of what's done here hard to grasp. That is, without seeing examples of how it's meant to be used, it's tough to work out, for example, why it both initially executes the callback but also returns a function for doing so again).

Comment: Also I should point out to the OP that `orig_fn.bind.apply` is pretty odd. It's actually identical to `Function.prototype.bind.apply` so the reference to orig_fn may be confusing there; it's just being pulled from that for convenience, and then orig_fn is supplied as the context on invocation of apply).

Comment: function result(data) {
 console.log( a );
}


var f = asyncify(result); f(); //f will always be invoked in async way

Comment: I mean function result will be always invoked in async way by wrapping it in asyncify function.

Comment: I'd caught that -- what I hadn't caught was why the 'intv' timeout would ever want to execute fn(). I see it now, though. In the event that it is called in its initializing tick, fn gets redefined for execution in intv. It makes sense. But it seems almost deliberately abstruse to me.

Comment: If you can add some more details how you see flow of execution Semicolon? What does "orig_fn.bind.apply" do?Thanks.

Comment: I'll post an answer with a shorter, clearer version of this code -- but with the caveat that it's possible I'm simply missing some feature of it that serves a less obvious purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code seems to be an very convoluted way of saying this:

```
function asyncify(cb) {
    return function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            cb.apply(this, arguments);
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

But I should emphasize ‘seems.’ Perhaps I’m missing some important nuance in the back-and-forth above.

As for `bind.apply`, that’s a little trickier to explain. Both are methods on every function, which allow you to invoke it with a specified context (`this`) and in the case of `apply`, it accepts arguments as an array.

When we "apply" `bind`, *bind itself* is the function which is being applied -- not the object apply lived on, which could have been anything. Therefore, it might be easier to begin making sense of this line if we rewrite it like this:

```
Function.prototype.bind.apply(...)
```

Bind has a signature like this: `.bind(context, arg1, arg2...)`

The arguments are optional -- often they are used for currying, which is one of the main use cases for `bind`. In this case, the author wishes to bind the original function to (1) the current `this` context, (2) the arguments which the "asyncified" function was invoked with. Because we don’t know in advance how many arguments need to be passed along, we must use apply, where the arguments can be an array or an actual `arguments` object. Here's a very verbose rewrite of this section that may help illuminate what occurs:

```
var contextOfApply = orig_fn;
var contextWithWhichToCallOriginalFn = this;

var argumentArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

argumentArray.unshift(contextWithWhichToCallOriginalFn);

// Now argument array looks like [ this, arg1, arg2... ]
// The 'this' is the context argument for bind, and therefore the
// context with which the function will end up being called.

fn = Function.prototype.bind.apply(contextOfApply, argumentArray);
```

---

**Actually...**

I can explain how the simple version I provided differs. On reviewing it again I caught what that missing nuance was that led its author to go through that weird dance at top. It is not actually a function for making another function "always async". It is a function that only ensures it is async *once* -- it guards against executing the callback during the same tick in which it was created but thereafter, it executes synchronously.

It’s still possible to write this in a friendlier way though, I think:

```
function asyncify(cb) {
    var inInitialTick = true;

    setTimeout(function() { inInitialTick = false; }, 0);

    return function() {
        var self = this;
        var args = arguments;

        if (inInitialTick)
            setTimeout(function() { cb.apply(self, args); }, 0);
        else
            cb.apply(self, args);
    }
}
```

Now I should note that the above does not actually do what it says. In fact the number of times that the function will execute using a timeout vs. synchronously is kind of random using either this or the original version. That's because setTimeout is a lame (but sometimes fine) substitute for setImmediate, which is clearly what this function really wants (but perhaps can't have, if it needs to run in Moz & Chrome).

This is because the millisecond value passed to setTimeout is kind of a "soft target". It won't actually be zero; in fact it will always be at least 4ms if I recall right, meaning any number of ticks may pass.

Imagining for a moment that you’re in a magical wonderland where ES6 stuff works and there’s no weird hand-wringing over whether to implement a utility as fundamental as setImmediate, it could be rewritten like this, and then it would have predictable behavior, because unlike setTimeout with 0, setImmediate really does ensure the execution occurs on the next tick and not some later one:

```
const asyncify = cb => {
    var inInitialTick = true;

    setImmediate(() => inInitialTick = false);

    return function() {
        if (inInitialTick)
            setImmediate(() => cb.apply(this, arguments));
        else
            cb.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```

---

**Actually Actually...**

There's one more difference. In the original, if called during the "current tick which is actually an arbitrary number of successive ticks" it will still only execute one initial time, with the final set of arguments. This actually smells a little like it might be unintended behavior, but without context I'm only guessing; this may be exactly what was intended. This is because on each call before the first timeout completes, fn is overwritten. This behavior is sometimes called throttling but in this case, unlike "normal" throttling, it will only take place for an unknown length of time around 4ms after its creation, and thereafter will be unthrottled and synchronous. Good luck to whoever has to debug the Zalgo thus invoked :)

Comment: Thanks for you explanation Semicolon. You are right about async  invocation, it has to be first time async and then it is sync.  Still this one is spinning my world: fn = orig_fn.bind.apply(orig_fn, [this].concat( [].slice.call( arguments ) ) . I don't get what he wants to do here...

Comment: I've added a deeper account of this portion.

Comment: How is orig_fn.bind.apply(orig_fn,... equal as Function.prototype.bind.apply(orig_fn,...  and thanks again for taking your time to answer me. Function.prototype is object.

Comment: It is a method of the prototype from which *all* functions inherit. I emphasized this because in that line, the first `orig_fn` is not actually "used" except to grab this generic method.

Comment: (In other words, the use of `orig_fn` there is arbitrary shorthand for "any function, I just want to do something with bind" just like `[]` in `[].slice` is a shortcut for "any array, I just want to do something with slice" that would be potentially misleading to someone trying to grapple with it like yourself.) I just remembered I answered a similar question a year ago that may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594957/binding-applying-constructors-in-javascript/23190790#23190790

Comment: Thanks for your deep explanations Semicolon. I got it now. I can't upvote it, becuse I stil don't have required reputation.

Comment: You're welcome -- it's kind of a confusing area because even if you understand what bind/apply/call do, combining them creates little brainteasers for which arguments go where. As the asker of the question, you should be able to accept it even if you can't upvote it (though whether it warrants that is your decision, so don't feel obligated).

Comment: I acccepted it. I am new here in stackoverflow as a registered user :)

Comment: Thanks. Since you're new it may be helpful to know that this question -- despite at its core being a good one, I think -- probably got downvoted by folks because it isn't written in a nice general "here's the thing..." way. A better title might be something like "How does "bind.apply" work in this code?" (you can still change that btw).

Comment: Your "Actually" version, while shorter, is IMO worse because you rely on two timers, whereas mine relies on one. My code was written that way to intentionally only use one timer (less memory, less CPU, etc). The behavior of two `setTimeout(..0)` timers is also notoriously unpredictable (in fact, I wrote a whole blog post on the --weird-- nature of timers).

Comment: Totally fair, I didn't mean to suggest it was necessarily better in practice (esp. since I don't actually know anything about its specific intended behavior or the context of its use), I was just trying to dissect what it achieves for the asker by refactoring the core idea into something simpler to understand, even f not identical for all use cases.

Comment: (BTW, at the time I provided this answer, I wasn't familiar with you or your work, but you are getify, correct? I very much enjoy the blog.)

Answer (score 1):

I want to put my 5 coins to the vision of this `asyncify` function example.

Here an example from `You Don't Know JS: Async & Performance` with my remarks and some changes:

```
function asyncify(fn) {
  var origin_fn = fn,
      intv = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("2");
        intv = null;
        if (fn) fn();
      }, 0);
  fn = null;
  return function internal() {
    console.log("1");
    if (intv) {
      // commented line is presented in the book
      // fn = origin_fn.bind.apply(origin_fn, [this].concat([].slice.call(arguments)));
      console.log("1.1");
      fn = origin_fn.bind(this, [].slice.call(arguments)); // rewritten line above
    }
    else {
      console.log("1.2");
      origin_fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
}

var a = 0;
function result(data) {
  if (a === 1) {
    console.log("a", a);
  }
}
...
someCoolFunc(asyncify(result));
a++;
...
```

So, how does it work?
Let's explore together.

I suggest to consider two scenarios - `synchronous` and `asynchronous`.

Let's suppose, that `someCoolFunc` is `synchronous`.

`someCoolFunc` looks like that:

```
function someCoolFunc(callback) {
   callback();
}
```

In this case console logs will fire in this order: "1" -> "1.1" -> "2" -> "a" 1.

Why so, let's dig dipper.

Firstly, is called `asyncify(result)` function. Inside the function we ask `setTimeout` to put this function

```
function () {
  console.log("2");
  intv = null;
  if (fn) fn();
}
```

at the end of tasks queue and invoke the function at the next tick of event loop (asynchronously), let's keep it in mind.

After that `asyncify` function returns `internal` function

```
return function internal() {
    console.log("1");
    if (intv) {
      // commented line is presented in the book
      // fn = origin_fn.bind.apply(origin_fn, [this].concat([].slice.call(arguments)));
      console.log("1.1");
      fn = origin_fn.bind(this, [].slice.call(arguments)); // rewritten line above
    }
    else {
      console.log("1.2");
      origin_fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
```

This result will be handled by `someCoolFunc`. We decided to assume, that `someCoolFunc` is `synchronous`. It leads to calling `internal` immediately.

```
function someCoolFunc(callback) {
   callback();
}
```

In this case this branch of `if` statement will be fired:

```
if (intv) {
  // commented line is presented in the book
  // fn = origin_fn.bind.apply(origin_fn, [this].concat([].slice.call(arguments)));
  console.log("1.1");
  fn = origin_fn.bind(this, [].slice.call(arguments)); // rewritten line above
}
```

In this branch we reassign `fn` value to `origin_fn.bind(this, [].slice.call(arguments));`. It guarantees, that `fn` function will have the same context as `origin_fn` function and the same arguments.

After that we get back from `someCoolFunc` to the line, were we increment `a++`.

All synchronous code was done. We agreed to keep in mind the snippet, which was postponed by setTimeout. It's time for it.

```
function () {
  console.log("2");
  intv = null;
  if (fn) fn();
}
```

The snippet above pooped up from tasks queue of event loop and invoked (we see in the console "2"). `fn` exists, we defined it in `internal` function, so `if` statement is passed and `fn` function is invoked.

Yey, that's it :)

But... something was left. Oh, yeah, we considered only `synchronous` scenario of `someCoolFunc`.

Let's fill the gaps and assume, that `someCoolFunc` is `asynchronous` and looks like taht:

```
function someCoolFunc(callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 0);
}
```

In this case console logs will fire in this order: "2" -> "1.2" -> "1" -> "a" 1.

As in the first case, at first is called `asyncify` function. It makes the same things - schedules

```
function () {
  console.log("2");
  intv = null;
  if (fn) fn();
}
```

snippet to be invoked at the next tick of event loop (firstly synchronous stuff).

From this step things go differ. Now `internal` isn't invoked immediately. Now it's put to the tasks queue of event loop. Tasks queue already has two postponed tasks - callback of setTimeout and `internal` function.

After that we get back from `someCoolFunc` to the line, were we increment `a++`.

Synchronous stuff is done. It's time for postponed tasks, in order as they were put there. First is invoked callback of `setTimeout` (we see "2" in the console):

```
function () {
  console.log("2");
  intv = null;
  if (fn) fn();
}
```

`intv` is set to `null`, `fn` equals to `null`, so, `if` statement is skipped. Task is poped up from tasks queue.

Left last step. As we remember in the tasks queue left `internal` function, it's invoked now.

In this case is fired this branch of `if` statement, due to `intv` was set to `null`:

```
else {
  console.log("1.2");
  origin_fn.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

In the console we see "1.2", then `origin_fn` is called using apply. `origin_fn` equals to `result` function in our case. Console shows us "a" 1.

That's it.

As we can see, it doesn’t matter, how `someCoolFunc` behaves -  `synchronous` or `asynchronous`. In both cases `result` function will be invoked at the time, when `a` equals to 1.