# Partially applying class constructor in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594957/binding-applying-constructors-in-javascript) about partially applying class constructors in JavaScript and tried to so something similar in Typescript.

First thin I notices is that `.bind` is untyped. So I tried to create my own type signature:

```
class Container<State> {
    constructor(public initialState: State) {}

    static of<State>(state: State): typeof Container<State> {
        return Container.bind(null, state)
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't seem to like `typeof Container<State>`. Any ideas how I can get this to work?

I could use a factory function, but I need to be able to use the `new` keyword on this for it to work with the existing setup I have that expects a class with no constructor arguments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `of` to return a no-arg `Container<State>` constructor. TypeScript allows you to denote a constructor type as the presence of a `new` function which returns an object.

```
type ContainerConstructor<State> = {
  new(): Container<State>;
}

class Container<State> {
  constructor(public initialState: State) { }

  static of<State>(state: State): ContainerConstructor<State> {
    return Container.bind(null, state)
  }
}

const ctor = Container.of('hello');
const container: Container<string> = new ctor();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just to add, I'm not sure if this is newly supported but at least in TypeScript 3.1 you can eliminate the explicit constructor type: `static of<State>(state: State): new() => Container<State> { ... }`